# How do I make a redirect when the second user comes in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm new to react

I'm creating a rock paper scissors lizard spock game using socket.io and node.js.

I have a waiting screen and I have to send a link to the game to another person.
When the second player enters the game, I should be redirected from the waiting screen to the game screen to the second player. That's where I have a problem.
My solution is to emit the "redirect" command to the client at the right time, and on the client I have the useState hook, and when the command comes, the redirect becomes true.
And if the redirect is true, then a Redirect to the game screen should occur, but nothing happens.

I hope I explained it clearly

**server.js**

```
let waitingPlayer = null

io.on('connection', socket => {
socket.emit('connection')

if (waitingPlayer) {
    socket.emit('redirect')
    RpslsLogic(waitingPlayer, socket)
    waitingPlayer = null
    console.log('user with id ' + socket.id)
} else {
    waitingPlayer = socket
    waitingPlayer.emit('message', 'Waiting for an opponent')
    console.log('user with id ' + socket.id)
}})
```

**app.js**

```
const [socketId, setSocketId] = useState('')
    socket.on('connection', () => {
        setSocketId(socket.id)
        console.log(socket.id)
    })

  return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={() => <WaitingScreen socketId={socketId} />}/>
            <Route exact path={`/game/${socketId}`} component={Game} />
               <Redirect to={`/game/${socketId}`}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

**waitingscreen.js**

```
const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false)
  
    socket.on('redirect', () => {
        setRedirect(true)
        console.log(redirect)
    })

    return (

        <Container className={styles.container} maxWidth="sm">
            {redirect && <Redirect to={`/id/${props.socketId}`} />}
            <div>
                <p className={styles.copyText}>{"localhost:3000/id" + props.socketId}</p>
                <button>Bla</button>
            </div>
            <img src={Billy} />


        </Container>
    )
```

Here's a code
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-dewdney-fqjt1

Thank you!

Comment: Please include a [mcve] within the question itself.

Comment: Already done! thx

Comment: You're sending the `redirect` event to the second player's socket, not to the `waitingPlayer`. Is that desired?

Comment: @Bergi
No... I need to send it to the first player.

Comment: @Bergi omg you saved me! wtf with my eyes?! it was so easy, but I spend 3 days trying to solve this problem. You are the best!